# Overlapping in TOC when using default section prefix with renewcommand thesection

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, section-titles

I'm writing on an exercise report and I want to have the prefix "Exercise" in my section headings (eg. Exercise 1: The QGIS user interface). So I used `\renewcommand*{\thesection}{Exercise~\arabic{section}:}`. But now in my TOC the spacing is not correct. The prefix and the heading are overlapping:
[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{Exercise~\arabic{section}:}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{The QGIS user Interface}
Text, text, text...
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You could use `\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=5em]{section}` but you are using `scrreprt` in a very strange way, the ToC will look weird without chapters.

Comment: Or you could use `\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocdynnumwidth]{section}` (needs an additional run to adjust the width automatically).

Comment: @campa No, it works at least with KOMA-Script version 3.22 and current version is 3.32.

Comment: @campa Search for `dynnumwidth` in the documentation (page 362 in scrguide.pdf of v3.23). This option can be used for `\RedeclareSectionCommand` with prefix `toc` (same as for `numwidth` and `tocnumwidth`). But your KOMA-Script version is really outdated.

Comment: Thank you! `\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocdynnumwidth]{section}` works perfectly!